# I need to send json data in one server app.py to another server app.py service?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, redis, server-sent-events

the below service  have the json data.that data is fetching from mongodb.

```
@app.route('/notifications',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def notifications():
    detailes = Notifications.objects()
    dt=[]
   for i in detailes:
       data={}
       data['usertype'] = i.usertype
       data['user_id'] = i.user_id
       data['date_time'] = i.date_time
       data['message'] = i.message
       data['title'] = i.title
       data['status'] = i.status
       data['last_notification_time'] = i.last_notification_time
       json_data = json.dumps(data)
       test=json.loads(json_data)
       dt.append(test)
    return jsonify(dt)
```

now i need to send this final json data to another service which is in another server and another app.py. below is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from flask_sse import sse

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
 app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

 @app.route('/')
 def index():
     return render_template("index.html")

 @app.route('/hello')
 def publish_hello():
     sse.publish({"message": "Hello!"}, type='greeting')
    return "Message sent!"
```

i need to pass above json_data that is in variable "dt"  in the place of message [sse.publish({"message": "Hello!"}, type='greeting')] which is in hello service.

Answer (score 0):

Just inject dt to dictionary that passed to client.

```
def some_function_that_grabs_messages():
    return some_data

@app.route('/hello')
def publish_hello():
    dt - some_function_that_grabs_messages():
    sse.publish({"message": dt}, type='greeting')
    return "Message sent!"
```

**UPDATE:**

*sse.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sse import sse
import pymysql as mysql

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

def conn_handler():
    conn = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='123456', database='feedparser', charset='utf8mb4')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT title FROM articles WHERE id < 30")
    data = cur.fetchall()  
    conn.close()
    return data

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/hello')
def publish_hello():
    data = conn_handler()
    for title in data:
      sse.publish({"message": title[0]}, type='greeting')

    return "Message sent!"
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flask-SSE Quickstart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Flask-SSE Quickstart</h1>
  <script>
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('sse.stream') }}");
    source.addEventListener('greeting', function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += data.message+"<br />";
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        alert("Failed to connect to event stream. Is Redis running?");
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
<div id="messages">

</div>
</html>
```

Run

```
$ gunicorn sse:app --worker-class gevent --bind localhost:8000
```

Comment: can u explain clearly where i need to put the code .thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response but I m using mongodb database .